# installing phpspreadsheet on server where already vendor folder exists

Tags: composer-php, vendor, phpspreadsheet

I am new to the composer. I already have vendor folder for `mpdf` library. All `mpdf` functions are working. Now I want to install `phpspreadsheet` library on a server. Can someone explain how to install it? What will be its default location? Can both the libraries reside within common vendor folder?

Comment: How did you installed `mpdf`? Can you show your `composer.json`? Installing second library should not really differ from installing first one.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Spreadsheet shouldn't conflict if you install it with composer; that's what composer does